# Exibir input baseado no option de um select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu quero exibir um `input` baseado no `option` que eu escolher através de um `select`.

Se eu selecionar `1` ele mostra o `input 1`, se eu selecionar `2` ele mostra o `2` mas dá um `hide()` no `1`. Atualmente o código está assim:

```js
$('.select').on({change: listChildren}).trigger('change');

function listChildren(){
  
  if ( $(this).val() != '' ) {
    children = $('option').val();
    $("#" + $(this).val() ).show();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name='options' class="select">
  <option value=''>Select</option>
  <option value='option-1'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='option-2'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='option-3'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" placeholder="exemplo 1" class="one" style="display: none" id="option-1"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="exemplo 2" class="two" style="display: none" id="option-2"/>
```

Estou conseguindo mostrar, mas não conseguindo fazer o `hide()`.

Comment: o input a ser mostrado tem que ter alguma ligação com o valor selecionado, por exemplo, o input tem um ID onde, o valor é o mesmo da opção selecionada?

Comment: isso mesmo! na verdade hoje ele ja ta conseguindo fazer o show. o problema esta no hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione uma `class` a todas as `input`. Depois basta colocar um `hide()` na `class` e assim no grupo e um `show()` pelo `id` no elemento específico:

```js
      $('.select').on({change: listChildren}).trigger('change');

      function listChildren(){

        if ( $(this).val() != '' ) {
          children = $('option').val();
          $(".input").hide();
          $("#" + $(this).val() ).show();
        }

      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='options' class="select">
      <option value=''>Select</option>
      <option value='option-1'>Option 1</option>
      <option value='option-2'>Option 2</option>
      <option value='option-3'>Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" placeholder="exemplo 1" class="one input" style="display: none" id="option-1" />

    <input type="text" placeholder="exemplo 2" class="two input" style="display: none" id="option-2" />
```

Comment: Boa Samir, era isso mesmo ;)